# Why is \$R_{eq}=0\$ ?and because the \$\tau=\infty\$.so in fact inductor is always in the Transient state and be charged?

Tags: inductor, homework, transient

There is a circuit,\$SW1\$ will be closed at \$t=0s,\$and \$SW2\$ will be opened at \$t=10ms\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLqYcp.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now i know that when \$t<0s\$ and \$t=0^+s\$,the \$i_L(t) =75mA\$,and the book also shows me the \$i_L(t)\$ when  \$10ms >t\ge0\$

\$\tau=\frac{L}{R_{eq}}=\frac{10mH}{0}=\infty\$

so \$i_L(t)=i_L(\infty)+[i_L(0)-i_L(\infty)]e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}=75mA\$

I have some question about the formulas above

1.Is it because that there is no resistor in the Charging path of inductor,so the \$R_{eq}=0\$ ?

2.\$i_L(t)=i_L(\infty)+[i_L(0)-i_L(\infty)]e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}=i_L(\infty)(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}})+i_L(0)\$,

and \$\tau=\infty\$,so is the inductor always be charged?

because \$i_L(\infty)(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}})\$ is the  charging formula of inductor,and \$\tau\$,the charging time ,is also \$\infty\$,so theoretically,inductor is always in the Transient state and be charged?

Is my thinking right??

Comment: I think it would help you to redraw the circuit to show the equivalent circuit for \$0 \le t \le 10\$ms and also for \$t \ge 10\$ms. That should clarify most of your questions. For one thing, you will see the \$\tau\$ is not the same in these two cases.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it because that there is no resistor in the Charging path of inductor,so the \$R_{eq}=0\$ ?

It's because at \$t=0^+\$, SW1 is closed and SW2 is open. That puts a short in parallel with the inductor.

> \$i_L(t)=i_L(\infty)+[i_L(0)-i_L(\infty)]e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}}=i_L(\infty)(1-e^{-\frac{t}{\tau}})+i_L(0)\$,

and \$\tau=\infty\$,so is the inductor always be charged?

Yes, as the circuit stands during this time, there is no loss mechanism. Therefore the inductor does not discharge.